# How to form Json array from sql pdo data in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

The code that I have does not display what I need, tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
   $new_array =[];
  foreach($result as $row)
   {
    $array =[
        'id'=> $row["id"],
        'summ' => $row["summ"],
    ];
    foreach($array AS $key => $val) {
     $new_array[] = $val;
    }
   }
   echo json_encode($new_array);
```

Outputs the following result

```
["26","180","25","35","24","50","23","50","22","100"]
```

But I need the result to be different, and I can't.
Here's an example of how it should be:

```
[
{"26","180"},
{"25","35"},
{"24","50"},
{"23","50"},
{"22","100"}
]
```

Please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: The expected result isn't valid JSON. Instead of `{"26", "180"}`, don't you mean `["26", "180"]`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any rule behind this formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this :

```
foreach($result as $row)
   $array[] = ['id'=>$row["id"], 'summ'=>$row["summ"]];
echo json_encode($array);
```

for example if your $result contains such a array :

```
$result    = [['id'=>1, 'summ'=>2] , ['id'=>3, 'summ'=>4] , ['id'=>5, 'summ'=>6]];
```

the scripts output will be :

```
[
    {"id":1,"summ":2},
    {"id":3,"summ":4},
    {"id":5,"summ":6}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the inner loop:

```
$new_array = [];

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $new_array[] = [
        $row['id'],
        $row['summ']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($new_array);
```

That should give you the result:

```
[
    ["26","180"],
    ["25","35"],
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside other answer,

I usually use `array_map` for this kind of array transformation.

```php
$result = [['id' => 1, 'summ' => 2], ['id' => 3, 'summ' => 4], ['id' => 5, 'summ' => 6]];

$output = array_map(function ($item) {
    return [$item['id'], $item['summ']];
}, $result);
```